# How can I style the CSS of ONLY the Reward Points page?

Tags: magento-enterprise, reward-points, magento-reward

I'm fairly new to Magento. My current version is Enterprise 1.11.2.0  I was wondering how can I style the CSS of ONLY the Reward Points page?
Any help is appreciated! ive also attached a screenshot of the page I'm looking to edit.

[image]

Comment: You can use class  which class on element you want to style and use css which loads here. most probably style.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing i'd do, is open my browsers developer tools, and inspect the page elements for rewards points (for chrome see https://developer.chrome.com/devtools)

From this you can inspect the css file and css entry that is styling the rewards points elements.
the css file is in magentoroot/skin/frontend/enterprise/defaut or your theme name/css/

if the rewards points elements are using their own css, you can modify these entries to adjust your styling.

if it is a more common styling (ie one that is used in other elements on your site other than rewards points) you may need to modify the rewards points phtml file, to a new css style name, and enter you code into your css.
(remember clear caches etc after change)

hope that helps.
cheers

Comment: Thank you for taking the time. One more question, what if I wanted to insert a <br /> after "Your current balance is.... ($0.00)" line. What's the file that I would need to edit?

Comment: check your design theme from the  file  ,your theme> /template/reward/tooltip.phtml:

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to check the html for a ID you can use to nest your css classes.

If one of the outer divs has an ID, you can use that to add new css to existing classes. For example:

```
<div id="rewards">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h1>Rewards points</h1>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

While there might already be CSS for the h1 tag. If you use:

```
#rewards h1 {your css updates here...}
```

This will overwrite any other h1 classes you have in your css sheet. You can use this same process for all other classes you want to change.